# Nginx permission denied when making a post request with json containing a base64 string

Tags: php, json, nginx

When I try to make a post request with json:

```
{  
   "img":"base64code..." 
}
```

I get this 2 different errors:

> 2018/04/14 00:43:21 [crit] 2737#0: *1770 open()
>   "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body/8/01/0000000018" failed (13:
>   Permission denied), client: 93.102.222.191, server: localhost,
>   request: "POST /api/administration/create HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "mywebsite.com"

or sometimes:

> 2018/04/14 00:43:23 [crit] 2737#0: *1771 mkdir()
>   "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body/9/01" failed (13: Permission
>   denied), client: 93.102.222.191, server: localhost, request: "POST
>   /api/administration/create HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"

I changed permissions in this directory with:

```
sudo chown -R Bitnami /opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp 
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp
```

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I solver it with the following command:

> sudo chmod -R a+rwx /opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp

I hope this help others with the same problem.